# Move matching tabs to new tab group in pentadactyl

Tags: pentadactyl, tab-groups

Does anyone know if I can move all the tabs matching an expression into a different tab group?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution.

- The following Pentadactyl ex file (with embedded Javascript) should provide a command that will match the label of all tabs to a regular expression and move matching tabs to a group with specified id. Note that matching is case-insensitive.

  ```
  " tgroup-moveselected.penta
  " Provides the command tgroup-moveselected, which moves all tabs matching a
  " given regular expression to the group with specified id.
  " eg.  :tgroup-moveselected "penta" "pentadactyl"
  "      moves any tabs whose label matches /pentadactyl/ to the group with id "penta"
  " Requires the TabGroupie plugin.

  command! tgroup-moveselected 
      \ -nargs=+ 
      \ -description "move tabs matching regex to a given group" 
      \ -js tgroupMoveSelected(args[0], RegExp(args[1]))

  js <<EOF

  function getPlugin(s) {
      for (x in plugins.contexts) {
          if (x.contains(s))
              return plugins.contexts[x][s];
      }
  }

  var TabGroupie = getPlugin("TabGroupie");

  function matchingTabs(rx) {
      var alltabs = tabs.allTabs;
      var alltabs = gBrowser.getTabsToTheEndFrom(0);
      function matches(t) {
          return rx.test(t.label.toLowerCase());
      }
      var matching = alltabs.filter(matches);
      return matching;
  }

  function matchingTabsInGroup(rx) {
      var alltabs = gBrowser.getTabsToTheEndFrom(0);
      function matches(t) {
          return rx.test(t.label.toLowerCase());
      }
      var matching = alltabs.filter(matches);
      return matching;
  }

  function tgroupMoveSelected (targetgrp, rx) {
      var matching = matchingTabs(rx);
      var tgrpId = TabGroupie.getIdByTitle(targetgrp);
      var i, t;
      for (i=0; i<matching.length; ++i) {
          t = matching[i];
          TabView.moveTabTo(t, tgrpId);
      }
      TabView.hide();
  }

  EOF
  ```
- I've uploaded it to Github as a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/ff64f37d695bb4549e96.html), so you can download it from there if you like.
- This script requires the [TabGroupie](https://github.com/eri451/TabGroupie) plugin.

  **warning**: On my system, placing this plugin in `~/.pentadactyl/plugins` (to be loaded when Pentadactyl starts) breaks the tab groups functionality entirely. To fix it, I have to disable Pentadactyl, restart FF and reenable Pentadactyl. The solution seems to be to load TabGroupie *after* Pentadactyl has started (by removing it from the `/plugins/` directory and just sourcing once FF has started).

## Recommended Setup

- Save both [**tgroup-moveselected.penta**](https://gist.github.com/troyp/ff64f37d695bb4549e96.html) and [**TabGroupie.js**](https://github.com/eri451/TabGroupie) in your `~/.pentadactyl` directory.
- Add the following line to your `.pentadactylrc`:

  ```
  command! tginit :source ~/.pentadactyl/TabGroupie.js | source ~/.pentadactyl/tgroupmoveselected.penta
  ```
- When you start FF, you can initialize the Pentadactyl tab group functionality with the command `:tginit`.
- If you want to use a certain pattern and/or tab group frequently, you can create a mapping or command as a shortcut. For example, if you wanted to use <kbd>C-m</kbd> as a hotkey to send all tabs with "pentadactyl" in the title to a tab group with id "penta", you could use this command:

  ```
  :map <C-m> :tgroup-moveselected "penta" "pentadactyl"<CR>
  ```